# Qt, unit testing and mock objects

Tags: unit-testing, qt, mocking

Qt framework has internal support for testing via QtTest package. Unfortunately, i didn't find any facilities in it that can assist in creating mock objects. Qt signals and slots offers a natural way to create a unit-testing friendly units with input (slots) and output (signals). But is it any easy way to test that calling specified slot in object will result in emitting correct signals with correct arguments? Of course i can manually create a mock objects and connect them to objects being tested, but it's a lot of code. Maybe it's some techniques exists that allows to somehow automate mock objects creation while unit-testing Qt-based applications?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you need a [QSignalSpy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalspy.html).

Comment: Thanks, seems that's i need. It was a standalone class, not in QtTest, so it's why i missed it :)

Comment: Actually it is in QtTest library but not in QTest namespace.

Comment: This is not always the way to go. E.g. if you don't want your tests to be timing dependent, you don't want to execute e.g. a QTimer and spy the signal. Instead you want to mock the timer. It's a pity none of the Q classes inherit from an interface that defines the public methods for the QClass. I just use gmock/fakeit where I implement an interface & a class that keeps a QTimer & forwards all methods to the QTimer.